# Having an issue in compressing Images in wordpress site

Tags: images, compression

I am having a trouble in getting my images to be compressed. Can images be automatically compressed? Is there any other solution for images compressing because its increasing my [technology rental](http://technologyrental.com.au/) website loading time and please help me out in finding the solution to overcome this images compression issue

Comment: Yes they are automatically resized by WordPress on upload, but using a default image quality setting. You can change the quality setting [e.g. with this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/image-quality/). Or did you mean something like webm?

Comment: (But deja vu - I think I've written an almost identical comment on an almost identical question before for someone who was just trying to plug their own website like this. That wasn't you, was it?)